# "He made a picture" vs. "he has made a picture"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

Which form is better to use?

> - He made a picture of his sister.
> - He has made a picture of his sister.

And why?

The situation in which I want to use it is as follows. This is my first sentence. No background or conversation was done before. I don't know the person I am talking to and neither does he. We see each other for the first time. Also he doesn't know my sister or anything like that.

Comment: Can you provide more of the context? Just like that both are correct. Also, you might want to try this site: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Why more information? There are only two states "0" or "1". 0 = Image doesn't exist. 1 =  Image does exist. I am talking about the state "1". No other speculations are needed. So, which tense would you suggest in this case?

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, dozens of times before. We even have a dedicated tag. Please search the site before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"He made a picture of his sister." is what you'll more frequently run into in the U.S., regardless of the context.

"He has made a picture of his sister" doesn't run off the tongue very easily.  The only situation that would really be used is if a child just drew a picture and someone was immediately commenting on it.  Even then, it would be wierd if a contraction wasn't in place.

"Look what he did!  He's made a picture of his sister!"

I'm mainly talking about conversational English, but this would apply to written work as well.

Answer (score 2):

The first places the making of the picture at a specific time in the past. The second suggests that the picture was made quite recently and that that fact is relevant to what has gone on previously in the conversation.

Comment: So which one to use?

Comment: It depends on what has gone on previously in the conversation.

Comment: Nothing. This is my first sentence. I don't know the person and he doesn't know me or my sister or any other background.

Comment: It still depends on the context.

Comment: Here is the context: **This is my first sentence. No background or conversation was done before. I don't know the person I am talking to and neither does he. We see each other for the first time. Also he doesn't know my sister or anything like that.**

Comment: The context includes what follows, and it also includes the wider social framework.

Comment: And? Which form do you suggest to use when talking non-specifically? The past simple? I guess so, because the thing started and ended in the past. So why would you be confused which tense to use? PLease, explain. I am interested in your logical proccess how you see this thing from a native English speaker POV. Thank you in advance.

Comment: All I can tell you is that, at least in British English, the present perfect construcion is used to relate something that has happened, usually in the fairly recent past, that has some kind of bearing on the present situation.